# SQL query to list cities in which employee did not work

Tags: sql

SQL query to list cities in which employee did not work from below
"employee" table:

| name | city |
| --- | --- |
| srini | seattle |
| ross | atlanta |
| rich | redmond |

Example: if I give "srini", query should return "Atlanta" and "Redmond"

I tried below 2 queries with no luck, it returns empty results:

1. ```sql
    SELECT t1.city 
    FROM employee t1 
        JOIN employee t2 ON t1.name=t2.name 
    WHERE t1.city != t2.city 
    WHERE name='srini'
   ```
2. ```sql
   SELECT city 
    FROM (SELECT city FROM employee WHERE name='srini') as e1 
    WHERE city <> e1.city
   ```

Comment: Please don't tag conflicting RDBMS. Just tag the one you are *really* using. I also suggest getting into the *good* habit of making use of whitespace and line breaks. Single lines of code are difficult to read.

Comment: One of those at least shoudl return an error 2 WHERE clauses are not allowed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
select distinct city
from employee
where city not in
(select city
from employee 
where name = 'srini')
```

Basically it's selecting all city names that don't exist in a row where `name`  is `'srini'`

Answer (score 1):

SQL is such fun. I'd go with a `GROUP BY` query, where I use the `HAVING` clause to only return cities where no srini lives.

```
select city
from employee
group by city
having sum(case when name = 'srini' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Core ISO/ANSI SQL, i.e. every dbms is expected to support it.

Or use `EXCEPT`:

```
select city from employee
EXCEPT
select city from employee where name = 'srini'
```

Core ISO/ANSI SQL, i.e. every dbms is expected to support it.